# Should I use Objective-C 1.0 or 2.0 for iOS Development?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-developer-program

I'm new to iPhone developing.I know that use Objective-C language but I don't know it use Objective-C 1.0 or Objective-C 2.0 on Mac OS Snow leopard.

Advice me please.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C 2.0.  In fact, using current dev tools it is not easy to use 1.0.

TO expand a bit:

O-C 2.0 has such features as

- properties
- garbage collection (except on iOS)
- non fragile instance variables
- fast enumeration
- 64 bit support

It's worth it for properties and fast enumeration alone in my opinion.

And I think there is no supported version of iOS that does not support O-C 2.0.

Why would you not use it?

Answer (score 2):

you should be using objc-2.

it is unusual to use objc-1 for ios development at this point in time.